# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid because of fields that have to be unique, although sequence for that fields is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot

Good day. i get this error

```
1) Subscription 
     Failure/Error: @subscription = FactoryGirl.create(:subscription)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Encountered errors: Email already exists, Login already exists
```

Although in a FactoryGirl i specify the uniqueness of these fields^

call for factory girl

```
@subscription = FactoryGirl.create(:subscription)
```

build can't be implemented, because

> should validate_uniqueness_of( :category_id).scoped_to(:user_id)

factories:

```
factory :subscription do
    association :category, factory: :advt_category 
    user
  end
factory :user do
    sequence(:login) { |n| "user__#{n}"  } 
    password "password"
    sequence(:email) { |n| "example__#{n}@example.com"}  
end
```

How to solve this error? why it appears?

**Update**

I ended up destroying all records for the User model in this spec

```
before do
User.destroy_all
end
```

Comment: have you checked that your test database is empty?

Comment: Please see update to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem most likely is, that your test DB is not clean when you start your specs. This can happen when a rspec exits prematurely, or is killed.

Your approach with `before { User.destroy_all }` works, but is tedious (since you may need to add it in other specs as well), and slow.

I'd suggest you make use of the [database_cleaner gem](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) and extend your rspec configuration like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before :suite do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.start }
  config.after(:each)  { DatabaseCleaner.clean }
end
```

When you are using Capybara for your request specs, change the `before :each` block to:

```
config.before :each do
  if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  else
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  DatabaseCleaner.start
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

Call a FactoryGirl for user and pass it into the subscription call

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) 
@subscription = FactoryGirl.create(:subscription, :user_id => @user.id)
```

As of why this happends we need to see more of the spec